# CSV and GDAL 1.10 in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, csv, import

It seems the GDAL upgrade from 1.9 to 1.10 changed the way CSV files are handled so that I now have a non-functioning QGIS. App hangs trying to import csv data file when previously had no problems with this and other csv text files.

I have deleted all data files, all files in the hidden .QGIS folder, all prefs and caches etc yet the app continuously tries to load the problematic file that I have deleted. Even replacing the bad file with another CSV file that works in another project fails to prevent the hang.

So now I have to recreate the project with customised colour schemes and 100s of hours of devt over the last 6 months while QGIS was stable.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem lies in the **project** file, you can edit that with any text editor, and delete manually the call of the CSV file.

At the moment, there is a lot of changing going on in QGIS and GDAL development. Assuming you are on Windows, I would advice to use the standalone QGIS Lisboa installer, not OSGeo4W. The standalone comes with GDAL 1.9.2, and is therefore save against recent GDAL changes.

If you need GDAL 1.10.0 features, you can install a standalone GDAL version from gisinternals, preferably the zip version (not exe!). This has a shell bat to start, and does not interfere with the QGIS installation.

And remember that QGIS Master is not intended for productive use!

**EDIT**

OSGeo4W still offers GDAL 1.9.2 only, so you upgraded a bit too early.

Comment: Hi Andre - thanks - I am on Mac. I will have a look at the project file, was unaware I could edit directly with a text editor. In the meantime, I have downgraded from QGIS 2 to 1.8 and back to GDAL 1.09. Missing QGIS 2 and GDAL 1.10 already.

Comment: Perhaps it might help you to install a virtual box with a Linux or Windows OS and make a seperate testing QGIS environment. In the Windows world, it is possible to run QGIS stable and Master separately. I'm not sure if it is possible on Mac.

Comment: I was able to edit the Project file - I suspect it is HTML or similar? but I bothed the edit - something about field mismatches so no joy. 
Macs certainly have the capacity to set up virtual box but I have spent my life dealing with Windows at work and avoid it at home! thanks for suggestions/help

Comment: I should add I am an ecologist and am doing all the mapping as a volunteer for a not for profit community group, so i am learning as I go. Helping group prepare maps to assist with local conservation work/efforts.

Comment: The project file is XML, similar to HTML syntax. If you hate Windows, you could try Ubuntu in a box. A lot to learn though, but so did I.